# Cygpath and accents (àèìòù)

Tags: cygwin, cygpath

`cygpath` doesn't seem to correctly handle paths with accents, e.g.

```
C:\cygwin64\bin>cygpath --absolute -C UTF8 "C:\foo\àòè\foo2"
```

prints

```
/usr/bin/"C:/foo/àòè/foo2"
```

whereas I would expect:

```
/cygdrive/c/foo/àòè/foo2
```

The same path without accents yields the expected result:

```
C:\cygwin64\bin>cygpath --absolute -C UTF8 "C:\foo\aoe\foo2"
/cygdrive/c/foo/aoe/foo2
```

Am I doing something wrong?

------ **EDIT 1**

I'm using Cygpath 2.6.0 on Win 10.

```
C:\cygwin64\bin>cygpath --version
cygpath (cygwin) 2.6.0
Path Conversion Utility
Copyright (C) 1998 - 2016 Cygwin Authors
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

C:\cygwin64\bin>locale
LANG=
LC_CTYPE="C.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="C.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="C.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="C.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

As far i see, after Adrian answer, I think that the problem is that I'm trying to use cygpath without running cygwin bash, because using that i don't have any problem.

```
$ cygpath --absolute -C UTF8 "C:\foo\àèò\foo2"
/cygdrive/c/foo/àèò/foo2
```

But I need to use cygpath directly without bash, do you think there is a way?

Comment: For me it also works as expected without `mintty`/`bash` directly in a Windows terminal (`cmd.exe`) on Windows 10.

Comment: Just installed cygwin 32bit and with cmd.exe I got the same issue. I just tried with powershell and it works. I really don't know what think.

Comment: Can confirm now, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of `Cygwin`/`cygpath` do you run? I can't duplicate this:

```
$ cygpath --absolute -C UTF8 "C:\foo\àòè\foo2"
/cygdrive/c/foo/àòè/foo2

$ cygpath --version
cygpath (cygwin) 1.7.35
Path Conversion Utility
Copyright (C) 1998 - 2015 Red Hat, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

**EDIT**

Works:

- `cygpath-1.7.35` in `mintty.exe` (Cygwin), `cmd.exe` and Powershell.
- `cygpath-2.6.0` in `mintty.exe` (Cygwin) and Powershell.

Does not work:

- `cygpath-2.6.0` in `cmd.exe`

This seems to be related to quoting and there is a workaround. Specifying the path without quotes yields the correct result:

```
c:\cygwin\bin>cygpath --absolute -C UTF8 'C:\foo\àèò\foo2'
/cygdrive/c/cygwin/bin/'C:/foo/àèò/foo2'

c:\cygwin\bin>cygpath --absolute -C UTF8 C:\foo\àèò\foo2
/cygdrive/c/foo/àèò/foo2
```

I'm not sure if/how the `Cygwin` devs support running `Cygwin` applications outside a `Cygwin`-shell but since this worked before I'd say it's a bug, you should post it to their mailing list.

Comment: same on 2.6.0 version